# Installing Basement bathroom exhaust fan in a side wall rather than a ceiling

Tags: bathroom, basement

Can you vent an exhaust fan in a basement bathroom out the sidewall rather than the ceiling? If I vent it through the ceiling I would have to cut through 3 joists to vent my exhaust fan outside and tie it into an existing clothes dryer vent.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How would you get the air to the sidewall; through the eaves?

Comment: Will the fan itself be mounted in the wall, or just the exhaust vent?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can mount the fan on the wall. if the wall exhausts to the outside it would be no different than a wall mount exhaust vent in the main floor bathroom. You cannot mount it on an internal wall and just dump the air into a stud bay (I have seen this tried and failed).

Answer (score 1):

You can not

> tie it into an existing clothes dryer vent.

"The reasons being that you can't easily prevent backflow and you increase fire spread risk". ( Isherwood ).

Do your joist bays not run to an exterior wall ? ( *there are specific restrictions on how big a hole you can put in a joist*. )

You can mount a **made for a ceiling fan** and route the duct to and through an exterior wall.

You can mount a **made for a wall fan** on an exterior wall.